# How to set the axis name of a pandas Panel object?

Tags: python, pandas

Using the pd.core.panelnd I can build a 5D panel with arbitrary axis names, such as:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

axis_1 = pd.Index(np.arange(0, 4), name='axis_1') 
axis_2 = pd.Index(np.arange(0, 5), name='axis_2')                                   
axis_3 = pd.Index(np.arange(0, 6), name='axis_3')
axis_4 = pd.Index(np.arange(0, 7), name='axis_4')
axis_5 = pd.Index(np.arange(0, 8), name='axis_5')

data = np.random.randn(axis_1.size, axis_2.size, axis_3.size, axis_4.size, axis_5.size,)

Panel5D = pd.core.panelnd.create_nd_panel_factory(klass_name=str('Example'), orders=['axis_1', 'axis_2', 'axis_3', 'axis_4', 'axis_5'], slices={'axis_2': 'labels', 'axis_3': 'items', 'axis_4': 'major_axis', 'axis_5': 'minor_axis'}, slicer=pd.Panel)

Dict5D = {}
for i, value in enumerate(np.arange(axis_1.size)):
    Dict5D[value] = pd.Panel4D(data[i], labels=axis_2, items=axis_3, major_axis=axis_4, minor_axis=axis_5)

p5d = Panel5D(Dict5D)
```

As a result, the summary of my 5D panel shows the arbitrary names of the axes (axis_1, axis_2, ...):

```
p5d
<class 'pandas.core.panelnd.Example'>
Dimensions: 4 (axis_1) x 5 (axis_2) x 6 (axis_3) x 7 (axis_4) x 8 (axis_5)
Axis_1 axis: 0 to 3
Axis_2 axis: 0 to 4
Axis_3 axis: 0 to 5
Axis_4 axis: 0 to 6
Axis_5 axis: 0 to 7
```

My problem is that I am not able to change the axis names for a simple 3D pd.Panel:

```
data = np.random.randn(axis_1.size, axis_2.size, axis_3.size)
p3d = pd.Panel(data, axis_1, axis_2, axis_3)
```

I still get the conventional naming ('items', 'major_axis', 'minor_axis'):

```
p3d
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 4 (items) x 5 (major_axis) x 6 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 3
Major_axis axis: 0 to 4
Minor_axis axis: 0 to 5
```

So my question is simple, is there a way to change the axis names of a 3D Panel?

Thanks a lot!